# ParametricNDSolve not accepting equation

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve following differential equation $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+(a+\frac{2}{\pi}b\hspace{3pt}\tan^{-1}x)\hspace{2pt}y=0$$
To solve it in mathematica I wrote the following code

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + (a + b*((2/Pi)*ArcTan[x]))*
  y[x] == 0, y[-10] == Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]], y'[-10] == (-I)*Sqrt[a + b]*Exp[I*10*Sqrt[a + b]]}, y, {x, -10, 10}, {a, b}]
```

but I am getting following error where am I making the mistake?[image]

Comment: Works just fine. Try to `Quit` your Kernel and restart. Look at the last boundary condition, this evaluated to `True`

Comment: @user21 thanks. So is it a normal practice to restart the kernel when faced with such problem?

Comment: @no. This just a quick test. Somewhere you defined something (a variable perhaps) that made the last bc evaluate to `True`. When you need to reuse a variable as a symbol use `Clear` or `ClearAll`